# PHP strange behaviour with switch case and the string '-0'

Tags: php, switch-statement, zero

I've recently come across a very strange behaviour in the PHP switch case when dealing with the string `'-0'`.

```
/* 
The code below echos:
'How did that happen? "0" and "0" are two different strings.' 
*/

$myString = '-0';

switch($myString) {
    case '0':
       echo 'How did that happen? "-0" and "0" are two different strings.';
       break;
    case '-0':
       echo 'This is normal.';
       break;
}
```

> Oddly, the switch statement above executes case '0'.

Going back to the code above, it seems that **if you change the order of the cases and place case `'-0'` before case `'0'`, it seems to work fine and execute case '-0' as it should.** 
*Why is that?* Is there reasoning behind this strange behaviour?

Comment: That's because on php you not declare variable types, and then, -0 and 0 are numerically the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While writing this question, I found out that **PHP does NOT use
>   strict equality for validating switch cases** (unlike other scripting
>   languages such as *JavaScript*).

Therefore, `case '0'` executes if `'0' == '-0'`, and since that is true, runs that instead (because it checked for that case first).

If `case '-0'` was placed first, it checks for that first, therefore executing that case, and since both cases are valid / `TRUE`, **it runs the first case in the switch statement**.